# does a semi sphere have more drag in comparison to a flat plane with equal surface area?

Tags: drag, aircraft-physics

What the title says, some things to know is that these aren't solid shapes, think of a bowl and a sheet of wood.

Comment: Related on Physics.SE: [What shape has the highest drag coefficient?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/201633/52596)

Comment: Ask more questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it doesn't. This chart explains how.  [image]
https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Typical-drag-coefficients-for-regular-3-D-objects_tbl2_273771608

Comment: I read somewhere that the lowest drag streamline body has a fineness ratio of 3:1, surprisingly stubby.  The short and odd looking Questair Venture came every close to this ideal shape  http://www.questairventure.com/